# "Relating" Vs "Related" in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, deverbal

While studying an online article, I came to a sentence:

> The media firm had uploaded some videos on the internet *relating* to
>   these banks as well as Prudential Life Insurance and Life
>   Insurance.

As per my understanding *related* should come in place of *relating*. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: +1 Good question ... from my point of view both "feel" right, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I have no special insight here, but found this [over on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67703/relating-to-or-related-to)

Comment: @ShawnMooney  To my mind the very subtle distinctions drawn in those answers are purely idiolectal: you may conform your use to the difference, but you should not have any confidence that your hearers will (or should) draw the same distinction.

Answer (score 3):

*Relate* is used today both transitively and intransitively.

> We relate these videos to those banks.  >>  *videos **related** to banks*
>    And in fact the passive participle is virtually a *deverbal* now: it has lost its verbal sense and is an independent adjective.
>
> These videos relate to those banks.  >>  *videos **relating** to banks*

Consequently, either word is acceptable.

Comment: Agreed both are acceptable, and your deconstruction is perfectly accurate. But I think it's probably fair to say in OP's context most people would go for ***relating***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  You think? I really have no idea. NGrams on "videos relatxx to" say -ed in AE, -ing in BE until 1999 when it's overtaken by -ed.

Comment: I admit it's really just my "gut feel". But maybe it's relevant to note that Google Books claims 103K instances of ["some documents **relating** to"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22some+documents+relating+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as against only 4K for ["some documents **related** to"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22some+documents+related+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). And it seems to me those two search strings would nearly always be in effectively the same context as OP's example.

Comment: When I GB I get no totals reported. I get similar results to yours with NGram searches on "documents relatxx", but with -ed increasing and -ing declining over the last 40 years ... and more markedly in AE than in BE.

Answer (score -1):

**Related to** usually describes a permanent relationship, whether between people or ideas. The past participle by itself (related) functions like an adjective.

**Relating to** is used generally to denote a reference to something else.

A more confusing example of the terms can be taken as:

> Do you have any information **related to**/***relating to*** ice hockey?

Here, both of them appear to give the same meaning but they are still different in the following sense.

> Do you have any information **relating to** ice hockey?

This would mean that you want information which is actually about *ice-hockey*.

> Do you have any information **related to** ice hockey?

This would mean any information which may even vaguely be considered having a connection is considered.

Comment: I think this is a spurious distinction in meaning.